# Why does this site have no decoration?

Tags: discussion

Is there a reason this site has no header?

I know that greens appreciate austerity, but it seems unlikely that a bit of color will increase the site's carbon footprint by much. This "under construction" look is surely not helping to attract new members.

I would propose my services but I am not a designer.

Comment: I think this question probably belongs on meta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All StackExchange sites launch initially as a 'beta' site with the same basic theme.
Once the site has proven itself (has a sufficiently large user base and gets enough high-quality questions and answers), it will "graduate" and earn it's own design. More info on this can be found [in this question on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76338/164138) or in [in this StackExchange blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme/)

Thank you for you offer to help, but the best way to speed up graduating from beta is to ask good and interesting questions and provide excellent answers.

Comment: Interesting linked post. Seems I agree with UncleZeiv's comment under it: "I like the new theme but the total absence of graphics and its extreme 'plainness' gave me the impression of a parked domain."

Comment: @Jortstek There is an SE logo in the top bar, but I agree that it isn't an eye-catcher